Compare Images and return Similarity Percentage (for logo's)
Let's say I have 2 image's


This has same logo so the result should be more then 90%
Here are another 2 logo'senter image description here
Now we have another 2 photos


This are also same images So result must be positive.
The problem I am encountering is, upon swapping images and comparing the logos of "Audi" and "Olympic," the similarity score exceeds 75%, despite the images being entirely distinct. I have attempted methods such as edge detection to resolve this discrepancy, but they have proven ineffective. Could you suggest an appropriate approach to address this problem?

what you call "entirely distinct" is objectively still quite similar. you will have to train an AI model to understand your notion of difference. -- you have presented none of the work you say you did on the problem. [ask], [mre]
